# Is there a way in PyCharm to check an object's methods while debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

While debugging in PyCharm, it's easy to check an object's fields while execution is suspended.  Is there a way to similarly check the object's methods from the IDE, or is this a feature that has just not been implemented by JetBrains?  The builtin `hasattr` function checks for both, so one would think it would be an easy feature to implement in the IDE.

Comment: As a side note you may use `dir(object)`

Comment: you can vote this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27760

Comment: Vote on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14849 .  PY-27760 is locked because it duplicates PY-14849.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I add `dir(variablename)` to the watch window to achieve this. If it's not visible, activate it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> (or `View/Tool Windows/Debug`).

[image: PyCharms Watches]

Another option is to use "Evaluate Expression" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) and do the same

[image: PyCharms Evaluate Expression]

Using Community Edition 4.0.4 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 if that should matter.